# Extract value from SetterBar

Tags: functions

I have a question about the SetterBar function. Is there any way to extract the selected value to use it further?

```
myValue = SetterBar[2, Range[5]]
myValue * 2
```

Comment: does `2 Setting[myValue]` give what you need?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Setting

You can use [`Setting`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Setting.html):
[image]

```
myValue = SetterBar[2, Range[5]]
```

[image]

```
2 Setting[myValue]
```

> ```
> 4
> ```

#### Dynamic

Alternatively, you can to  use `Dynamic`:

[image]

#### Generalized input

Finally, you can use `Setting` and Evaluate In Place the setter bar to make the setter bar an input expression:

Highlight `SetterBar[2, Range[5]]` in

```
Setting[2 SetterBar[2, Range[5]]]
```

and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to get

[image]

Select a value in the setter bar and hit <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to get

[image]

[image]

**See also:** the tutorial [Generalized Input](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GeneralizedInput.html)